# select columns from heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I created the heatmap using this script:

```
RPKM_df= data.frame(GENES= table_tot_tissues$genes, RPKM)
dat = RPKM_df[,-1]
datmatrix= as.matrix(dat)
heatmap_RPKM= heatmap.2(datmatrix, trace = "none", Colv=FALSE, dendogram = 'row', 
                        density = "none", col = bluered(20), 
                        cexRow = 0.6, cexCol = 0.9, margins = c(8,14), scale = "row", 
                        hclust =function(x) hclust(x,method = "average"))
```

and I obtained this heatmap: [image]

but now

1. I need to extract only the columns called ova and testes to make a comparison.
2. Select some clusters of genes(the most expressed) to evaluate the gene expression in both tissues.

Comment: both of those columns should be in your matrix `datmatrix`. do `datmatrix[c("ova","testes")->datmatrix.select` to get all the data. To filter on some value of gene expression, you can than do datmatrix.select %>% filter(value => "some threshold").  you might have to do some munging to get the data in shape

Comment: sorry but it doesn't give me the expected result. I obtained a heatmap that is composed by the two columns specular in colours

Comment: ok do  `head(datmatrix)` what do you get?

Comment: ova                 testes
1   5.0730217                      90.2201082
2   4.4356482                       0.5275397
3   0.3397144                       8.1337453
4   1.2082854                       6.2621722
5   2.3547895                       41.6279899
6 266.7380691                    74.0451493

Comment: So I'm confused. Is therw only those 2 columns in datmatrix or are you pasting what you want to get out of it. And if those are the the two columns you need what's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm very sorry! these are the data of two columns, but I want to create a heatmap with only these two columns, but the result is a strange heatmap in which the columns seem to have identical gene expression with opposite colours, but I can't explain how it is possible

Comment: Okay, well then have a look at the data first. do a diff on the columns and average that to see what you get. that should clue you in